# why document.getElementID.width is not assigned a value rather shows as null reference?

Tags: javascript, jsp

this snippet contains resize function  and "programCell" element* is assigned from same jsp now when  onresize=resizeCells() how thw width value will assigned?

```js
function resizeCells(){
 var cProg = 0;
 
 //alert("taille avant "+document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg).offsetWidth);
 //while (document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg) != null && document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg) != undefined){
  //alert("taille avant "+document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg).offsetWidth);
  //document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg).width = document.getElementById("programTitle").offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("programTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  ***Unable to set property 'width' of undefined or null reference**
  document.getElementById("phaseCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("phaseTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("modelYearCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("modelYearTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("spillCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("spillTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("keyCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("keyTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("sizeCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("sizeTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("logCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("logTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("canChangeCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("canChangeTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
  document.getElementById("forcedCell"+cProg).width = (document.getElementById("forcedTitle").offsetWidth-19)+"px";
  cProg++;
```

```html
<body onload="showMsgs();" onkeypress="javascript:submit()" onresize="resizeCells();" > 
  
  */codingss*****
  
  
   <TABLE align="left"   cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
       <% boolean bColored = false;  %>
       <%int cLignes = 0;%>
       <logic:iterate id="searchedData" name="monitorForm" property="listData" indexId="index">
       <% bColored=!bColored; %>          
       <tr class="<%=(bColored?"oddC":"evenC")%>">
           <td align="center"  id="programCell<%=cLignes%>" ><bean:write name="searchedData" property="programcode"/></td>
           <td align="center" id="phaseCell<%=cLignes%>" ><bean:write name="searchedData" property="phase"/></td>
           <td align="center" id="modelYearCell<%=cLignes%>" ><bean:write name="searchedData" property="modelYear"/></td>
           <logic:equal name="searchedData" property="spillFlag" value="1">
            <td align="center" id="spillCell<%=cLignes%>" ><a HREF="javascript:cancelSpilling('<bean:write name="searchedData" property="program"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="phase"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="modelYear"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="keyn"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="existEvol"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="keyEvalNo"/>')"><IMG src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/right.gif" border=0></a></td>
           </logic:equal>
           <logic:equal name="searchedData" property="spillFlag" value="0">
            <td align="center" id="spillCell<%=cLignes%>"><a HREF="javascript:spilling('<bean:write name="searchedData" property="program"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="phase"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="modelYear"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="keyn"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="existEvol"/>','<bean:write name="searchedData" property="keyEvalNo"/>')"><IMG src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/wrong.gif" border=0></a></td>
           </logic:equal>
```

Comment: can you show the markup?

Comment: Your browser has a fully-featured, built-in debugger. Learn to use it, and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unable to set property 'width' of undefined or null reference" is pretty clear. It means `getElementById` returned `null` (or `undefined`, but it doesn't do that), which means that the element didn't exist as of when `getElementById` was called. So there is no element with the `id` "programCell0" in your DOM as of that call.

You're probably running the code too soon. Scripts run when the parser encounters them (unless you use `async` or `defer`), which means if they're above the elements you refer to in the HTML, they won't find them. Put the script at the *end* of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Once you've solved that problem, the next problem is that elements don't have `width` and `offsetWidth` properties. To *assign* a width to an element, you probably want to write to `element.style.width`. Remember that's a CSS width, so it's a string and needs units, e.g. `"10px"`. To *get* the current style value for an element, you can't just use `style` because that only reflects inline styles. You need to use `getComputedStyle(element)` on standards-compliant browsers, and `element.currentStyle` on older IE. Use search to find examples.

Comment: i use IE11 and now element.currentStyle  will support?

Comment: @varun: IE11 supports the standard `getComputedStyle` unless it's rendering your page in [in]Compatibility Mode, in which case, make it not do that. :-)

Comment: @Crowder plese help to fix this.. only when the form submits  "programCell" will get its value from cLignes then  when onresize event willl invoke and how the width will be assigned to it ?

Answer (score 1):

[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) doesn't have width property,  you need to set the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property

Use `Element.style.width` instead

For example

```
document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg).style.width = (document.getElementById("programTitle").offsetWidth-1)+"px";
```

Comment: That doesn't fit the symptom. (It's the *next* problem, though.)

Answer (score 1):

`Unable to set property 'width' of undefined or null reference` refers to the fact that the `document.getElementById("programCell"+cProg)` returns null. And you are trying to access a property of a null object.

Check your id. You can do it by inspecting the DOM through developer tools or the html file if you have it handy.

Hope this helps!